# 2D ArrayList Index Out of Bounds

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I was implementing 2D Array for my APP.
But unfortunately I had this error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.application.recast, PID: 18534
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application.recast/com.application.recast.SplashScreen}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
    Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
       at com.application.recast.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:60)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

What I am doing is that, I want to store specific item into specific index of 2D array.
Pretty new with 2D arraylist.
Here's my code.

```
ArrayList<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

mStrings.add("HI");
mStrings.add("HI2");
mStrings.add("HI3");
mStrings.add("HI4");
list.add(0,mStrings);

for(int x=0;x<list.size();x++){
    for(int y=0;y<mStrings.size();y++){
        Log.d("VALUE",String.valueOf(list.get(y)));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `String.valueOf(mStrings.get(y))`

Comment: Try my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to draw a hypothetical picture of a `List` of `List`. Here is one possible outer list, and its contents:

```
0: []
1: [a, b, c]
2: [d, e]
3: []
```

etc.

So, it is unlike a 2D array in that there is no uniform column size.

So you can see, the outer list at index 0 is empty, at index 1, there is a list with 3 items, etc.

Given this, to iterate over a `List<List<Object>>`, you'll have to check the size of the inside list each time *as well*:

```
for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < list.get(x).size(); y++) {
        Log.d("VALUE", String.valueOf(list.get(x).get(y)));
    }
}
```

Where `list.get(x)` itself return a list, and `list.get(x).get(y)` return a value in the sublist.

Update: or as @cricket_007 points out, you can just use the *for-each* style loop, for more readable code.

Answer (score 3):

**Issue** `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 at`

`list` has only `1` element mean `list.get(0)` but `for(int y=0;y<mStrings.size();y++){` will be executed 4 time hence **error here `list.get(y)`**

`list` contains only single element i.e. `mStrings`

and further **for single element** in `list` this logic works but for multiple elements in `list` you need to fetch the element from `list` then traverse it

```
for(int x=0;x<list.size();x++){
         ArrayList<String> sublist = list.get(x);
            for(int y=0;y<sublist.size();y++){
                //Log.d("VALUE",String.valueOf(sublist.get(y)));
                Log.d("VALUE at index "+y,sublist.get(y));
            }
        }
```

Note : now `String.valueOf(` is unnecessary because your data is string type

Comment: Note: The `Log` methods throw exception with a null message, so `String.valueOf` helps with that

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating `mString ArrayList` size with `list ArrayList`

**Conditions**

> If you have `mString ArrayList` size is greater than `list ArrayList`
>   then there will be `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

**Try this**

```
for(int x=0;x<list.size();x++){
Log.d("VALUE",String.valueOf(list.get(x)));
    for(int y=0;y<mStrings.size();y++){
        Log.d("VALUE2",String.valueOf(mStrings.get(x)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the index?

If not, you can use an enhanced for loop.

```
for(List<String> innerList : mStrings){
    for(String s : innerList){
        Log.d("VALUE", s);
    }
}
```

Your error is that `list.size() != mStrings.size()`

Comment: yes I need the index. Because I am inputting some values in different indexes.

Comment: Alright, then the other answers provide that solution

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using 2D array list, So in implementation part, What You need to do is

```
ArrayList<T> A = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> B = new ArrayList();
```

This means Arraylist B is storing Arraylist A in each of there index.
So for getting that stored element in B. You need to do like this.

```
ArrayList<T> A = B.get(i); // this will return the list stored at index i or you can say ith row.

//now
T a = A.get(j); //this will return the item stored index jth.

//in one line
T a = (B.get(i)).get(j); // this will return the value stored at ith row and jth column.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your code

```
ArrayList<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

mStrings.add("HI");
mStrings.add("HI2");
mStrings.add("HI3");
mStrings.add("HI4");
list.add(0,mStrings);

for(int x=0;x<list.size();x++){
    for(int y=0;y<mStrings.size();y++){
        Log.d("VALUE",String.valueOf(list.get(y)));
    }
}
```

`list` has a single element, yet you try to reach its `y`'th element, when `y` will get bigger due to the size of `mStrings`. You will need `list.get(x).get(y)` instead of `list.get(y)`. It is better to define your inner `for` dynamically, to cope with the situation when the outer list has more elements:

```
ArrayList<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

mStrings.add("HI");
mStrings.add("HI2");
mStrings.add("HI3");
mStrings.add("HI4");
list.add(0,mStrings);

for(int x=0;x<list.size();x++){
    for(int y=0;y<list.get(x).size();y++){
        Log.d("VALUE",String.valueOf(list.get(x).get(y)));
    }
}
```